# sitting or seated

Tags: word-choice

I could see the man sitting/seated next to me shaking his head, thinking this is going to be a long flight.

Is there anything in the context that would make one of "sitting" and "seated" more appropriate to use?

Comment: If he was allocated the seat by the air crew (and presumably did not like being there) he was **seated** there by the crew. If he happened to be resting on a convenient park bench, he was **sitting** there.

Comment: @Weather Vane - This is the basis of a good answer. Why not turn it into one?

Comment: Also possibly [A man sitting here or seated here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/221258/a-man-sitting-here-or-seated-here).

Comment: @chasly-supports Monica thanks but I think it has been covered, several times. Here is [another](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/173447/correct-use-of-sit-was-sitting-was-seated-in-english-sentence).

Comment: One is seated on a horse, without a ticket to ride.